# adding custom fields to django registration

Tags: python, django

I am using the django registration module and trying to add custom fields:

```
RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(FarmerForm.base_fields)

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        user = super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).save(profile_callback=None)
        f = Farmer(user=user)
        f.farm = self.cleaned_data['farm']
        f.produce = self.cleaned_data['produce']
        f.produce_price = self.cleaned_data['produce_price']
        f.save()
```

For some reason though, 
the part below:

```
f = Farmer(user=user)
f.farm = self.cleaned_data['farm']
f.produce = self.cleaned_data['produce']
f.produce_price = self.cleaned_data['produce_price']
f.save()
```

doesn't execute.

What am I doing wrong?

What is the best way to add custom fields to django registration then? thanks!

Comment: you need to call `self.is_valid()` before you can use `cleaned_data`

Comment: what's the best way to add custom fields to django registration then? thanks!

Comment: @user2769816 just add them inside `__init__` after calling super. Example: `self.fields['field_name'] = forms.TextField()`

Comment: how can I make sure I validate the FarmerForm though?

Comment: @user2769816 karthikr already answered that, please refer to django docs on using forms, to see how it should be done.